# Why does this laravel package increase boot process by 3 seconds?

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed a fresh Laravel Application v9.3.8. I installed composer, moved .env.example to .env and generated the key. I am using php 8.1.11 The application runs fast.

When I add the package `codeat3/blade-simple-icons` the loading time takes 2-3 seconds. Even for such a route:

```
Route::get('/x', function(){
    return 'Is it still slow?' . (microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START);
});
```

When I do a dump at the end of the boot method from the service provider, the time is again only 0.2seconds.

[image]

The package itself is tiny https://github.com/codeat3/blade-simple-icons Why is it increasing my loading time by 2seconds?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling the cache? https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#caching

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes thats it! Thank yoU!

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: I'll let you do that, maybe throw some quick documentation in there, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#caching is using Blade Icons.

[For blade icons, its recommended to enable caching](https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#caching):

> When working with Blade Icons, and third party icon sets in particularly, you'll often be working with large icon sets. This can slow down your app tremendously, especially when making use of Blade components. To solve this issue, Blade Icons ships with caching support. To enable icon caching you can run the following command:
>
> `php artisan icons:cache`